# Knockout: XXX is not a function error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am learning Knockout.js and using `with:binding` to change the binding context as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap" data-bind="with: currentCat()">

    <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>
    <h3 data-bind="text: level"></h3>
    <div data-bind="text: count"></div>
    <img src="" alt="cute cat" data-bind="click: $parent.incrementCounter, attr: {src: imgSrc}">

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var cat = function() {
    this.name = ko.observable("Fossie");
    this.imgSrc = ko.observable("--");
    this.count = ko.observable(0);
    this.nicknames = ko.observableArray(["Meow", "Johnny"]);
};

var viewModel = function() {

    this.currentCat = ko.observable(new cat());
    this.incrementCounter = function() {
        this.currentCat().count(this.currentCat().count() + 1);
    }

};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

When I click on the image, I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: this.currentCat is not a function`

the same code worked without using `with` binding. Can anyone please explain what changed after I changed context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` looses its context when used as an event handler. Use `.bind`

```
this.incrementCounter = function() {
    this.currentCat().count(this.currentCat().count() + 1);
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Wow, that solved the problem. Thank you, sir.  Can you please elaborate what you meant by 'this looses its context when used as an event handler', and how binding fixed that problem?

Comment: @akshayKhot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Comment: Thank you for the link. Before using `with`, I had `data-bind="click: incrementCounter` and the same JS without bind. It worked that time. How come `with` make it fail?